# Power BI Query - Extract text between delimiters to a new column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table that contains a text column in the following format:

> "random text [ABC-######] other random text"

For all the rows containing "[ABC-" I would like to extract to a new column the "ABC-######" where ###### are random numbers at least 4 numbers but can be more.

this is what I got so far working:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if Text.Contains([TextColumn], "[ABC") then "FOUND" else "NotFound")
```

But I'm not able to extract the substring with numbers.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you
dk

Comment: Some clarifying questions:
Are square brackets a part of any string?
Does any possible string contain "ABC-"
Which regexp matches any source string?
"^\w+ \[ABC-\d{4,}\] \w+$",  
"^.*\[ABC-\d{4,}\].*$",  
"^.*\[[a-cA-C]-\d{4,}\].*$"

Comment: Thanks. i solved with:
`each if Text.Contains([TextColumn], "[ABC-") then (Text.Range((Text.Range([TextColumn], (Text.PositionOf([TextColumn], "[ABC-", Occurrence.First))+1, 14)), 0, (Text.PositionOf((Text.Range([TextColumn], (Text.PositionOf([TextColumn], "[ABC-", Occurrence.First))+1, 14)), "]", Occurrence.First)))) else "None")`
It might not look at the best solution but it is working, probably there are computational better ones. I don't need to extract the "[" "]" but just ABC-and the characters untill the following "]".

Comment: @d82k Your answer looks great! It's recommended on StackOverflow that if you find the answer to your question, add the answer yourself http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . BTW, if speed matters maybe you could avoid the `Text.Contains()` function and just call `Text.PositionOf([TextColumn], "[ABC-")` once; if the substring is not found, PositionOf will return -1.

Answer (score 3):

## Less complicated version

```
let
    tbl = #table({"TextColumn"}, {
        {"qwer"},
        {"qwer [ABC-1234] asdf"},
        {"qwer [ABC-1234]"},
        {"[ABC-1234] asdf"}
    }),
    AddColumn = Table.AddColumn(tbl, "ExtractedNumber", each try Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"[ABC-","]"})([TextColumn]){1} otherwise "None")
in
    AddColumn
```

### Should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved using:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
if Text.Contains([TextColumn], "[ABC-") then
(Text.Range((Text.Range([TextColumn], (Text.PositionOf([TextColumn], "[ABC-", Occurrence.First))+1, 14)), 0, (Text.PositionOf((Text.Range([TextColumn], (Text.PositionOf([TextColumn], "[ABC-", Occurrence.First))+1, 14)), "]", Occurrence.First))))
else "None")
```

As suggested in the comments

```
 Text.PositionOf
```

would result in being more fast.

Thanks